# Recordset loop doesn't return the last record

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, eof, recordset

I'm using the following code to loop through a recordset which suppose to transfer all selected records to the Word document in a tabular format. It works however it gives me all records except the last one (i.e. I select 4 records and it returns only 3 from the top).

```
Private Sub cmdWord_Click()
Dim oWord As Object 'Word.Application
Dim doc As Object 'Word.Document
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set doc = oWord.Documents.Open("D:\Working\Templates\Letter.doc")
oWord.Visible = True
Dim oAccess As Object
Dim dbs As Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim strCriteria As String

With oWord.ActiveDocument
    If .Bookmarks.Exists("Date") = True Then
        .Bookmarks("Date").Select
        If Not IsNull([Forms]![frmForReport_Preview]!Date) Then
            oWord.Selection.Text = (CStr(Format([Forms]![frmForReport_Preview]!Date, "mmm d, yyyy")))
        Else
            oWord.Selection.Text = ""
        End If
    End If

    If .Bookmarks.Exists("Table") = True Then

        Set dbs = CurrentDb
        strCriteria = "SELECT tblForLetter.ID, tblForLetter.DID, tblForLetter.AT, tblForLetter.Expr1, tblForLetter.L FROM tblForLetter WHERE (((tblForLetter.Print)=-1=True));"

        Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strCriteria, dbOpenSnapshot)
        oWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Table").Select
        oWord.Selection.Text = ""

        i = 1
        If Not (rst.EOF And rst.BOF) Then
            rst.MoveFirst
            Do Until rst.EOF = True
                doc.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells.Add
                doc.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells(i + 1).range.Text = rst.Fields(0)
                doc.Tables(1).Columns(2).Cells(i + 1).range.Text = rst.Fields(1)
                doc.Tables(1).Columns(3).Cells(i + 1).range.Text = rst.Fields(2)
                doc.Tables(1).Columns(4).Cells(i + 1).range.Text = rst.Fields(3)
                doc.Tables(1).Columns(5).Cells(i + 1).range.Text = rst.Fields(4)
                rst.MoveNext
                i = i + 1
            Loop
        Else
            MsgBox ("There are no records in the recordset.")
        End If

        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmForReport_Preview", acSaveYes
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete * From [tblForLetter]"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True

        rst.Close
        Set dbs = Nothing
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It may be a silly question but what does `rst.MoveLast` followed by `Debug.Print rst.RecordCount` actually print out? You should insert those lines after `rst.MoveFirst` to test.

Comment: Ok, I inserted these lines like this: If Not (rst.EOF And rst.BOF) Then _ rst.MoveFirst _ rst.MoveLast _ Debug.Print rst.RecordCount. I selected 4 records but only the second last was transferred to the Word document. In the immediate window it printed out 3.

Comment: What did `Debug.Print` print into the Immediate Window? And by the way, what do you mean with "I selected 4 records"? The records are selected by your `SELECT ...` statement.

Comment: ye, sorry, it printed out 3.

Comment: Ok, then your code is correct (it seemed correct from first and second glance, anyway). Look at your `SELECT` statement, maybe your `WHERE` clause is wrong.

Comment: By selecting records I mean that I select them in the form, then they are written to the table tblForLetter which is used in my code as a source of records to be transferred to the Word document. As a result the recordset should contain records from the tblForLetter with the value -1 in the Print field. So every time I select some records, my code returns one record less than I selected.

Comment: Then obviously you should find the error in the code setting the -1 and/or the `SELECT` statement you're using.

Comment: I can't see a mistake in the statement. Even if I look in the table tblForLetter it contains the exact number of records I selected in the form before (frmForReport_Preview). All of them has the -1 value. Say if i selected 4 records the table has 4 records with -1 value, but the recordset returns only 3 of them from the first to the second last and "forgets" about the last record...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly do you select the records in the form?

I'm suspecting this:

- The form is a continuous form
- The RecordSource of the form is `tblForLetter` or `SELECT * FROM tblForLetter` or something like this
- There's a checkbox on the form which has the `Print` column as the Control Source.
- So when you "select" a record by clicking its checkbox, the `Print` column in the respective row is set to `True` / `-1`.

If you're doing it like this, you should consider the following:

- When you change something in one of the rows *(in this case you check a checkbox, but it would be the same if you entered text into a text box, for example)*, this row goes into "edit mode".
  *(don't know if Access has a special name for it, so I'll just call it like this)*
- As long as that row is still in edit mode, **nothing is changed in the database**. You are just changing the controls in the GUI.
- The row stops being in edit mode when you set the focus to another row *(=by clicking on a control in another row)*.
- In **this** moment, Access actually saves your changes into the database.

So when you select multiple checkboxes, what really happens is this:

- You click on the checkbox in row 1
- Row 1 switches to edit mode, and the checkbox is checked in the GUI *(but not yet in the database)*
- You click on the checkbox in row 2
- This ends the edit mode in row 1 and saves the change into the database.
- Then row 2 switches to edit mode, and the checkbox is checked in the GUI *(but not yet in the database)*
- ...and so on.

Now there's an additional gotcha:
When a row is in edit mode, and you click on a control that's in the form's header or footer *(in other words, not in the "detail" area, the actual continuous part of the form)*, **that row stays in edit mode and the changes are not saved to the database yet**.

### So the strange behaviour that you are seeing is probably caused by this:

- You select four records by clicking on their check boxes.
- Then you click on the `cmdWord` button which triggers the code in your question, but in that moment, the fourth row is still in edit mode.
- This means that the checkbox is checked on the GUI only...but Access hasn't saved this to the database yet!
- So when you execute your query and filter by `... WHERE tblForLetter.Print=True`, you get only the first three selected rows, but not the fourth because in that moment, `tblForLetter.Print` is still `False` in the database.

### Solution:

Generally speaking, you need to make sure that no row is still in edit mode when you run the query that gets the selected rows from the table.

Without changing your code, you can see the difference when you select your four rows, **set the focus to another row so that the fourth row is saved as well**, and **then** click the button.

**To do this automatically in your code, you can requery the form's data source by just calling `Me.Requery` before selecting from the table.**
`Me.Requery` will reload the data in the form. If there's still a row in edit mode in that moment, edit mode will end first and the changes in that row will be saved to the database.

Comment: O god! that's amazing! Such an easy solution! thank you Christian very much! P.S. great guess by the way! My structure is little bit different, I use a make table query in the form frmForReport_Preview to actually create table tblForLetter with that selection statement. But anyway, your solution works perfectly!